# How to find memory leaks if they cause the app to crash?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-leaks, crash-reports

I used Leak Instruments to find Leaks and set `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES`. When I press a button or a particular row from tableView my app crashes and I am unable to find any information in Instruments.

I followed the tutorial here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks

How can I identify or get more information in Instruments when my app is crashing?
[image: Here is screenshot while app is crash]

Comment: Leaks can not cause crash (probably when memory runs out), but Zombie can

Comment: Can you add the crash report and some code?

Comment: if you get this crash on simulator also than run profiler tool with zombies option this will give you zombie object detailes.once you start this option go to the location where you get crash in application you will get flag click on that and enable option 3rd option in view in tool that may give you stack and click on the stack methods that display you code location of crash may cause or object may zombie.(in red color line).but this zombies option is not available for device.

Answer (score 2):

Use Zombie for finding out the Zombie message. It will show you Pink flag with message.

Comment: Refer this for more.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533650/ios-zombie-detection]

Comment: please accept this as an answer if you satisfy with my answer.

Comment: please accept this as an answer if you satisfy with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Zombie message by enabling from edit schema and in Run tab Checkmark Enable Zombie object and you can see released object from console

Answer (score 0):

Zombies are not the only thing you can have there.

The only way to find leaks is to you profiler with "Leaks" component.

Try also running Project / Analyze for static analyze of your code about memory management errors.

For crash - I think you just have error in code - not really leak. Enable exception breakpoint in your xcode to catch a problem !

http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions